# How to send myself information from work without revealing my personal account

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-workspace, privacy

At work we heavily use Gmail and Drive, and there are some emails and files I would like to somehow store or send myself to store and remember at my personal account.

However, I fear simply sending or sharing the file -- while not breaking any type of rules because I am talking about discounts, offers and similar stuff that they give us to go to the cinema, etc, nothing critical -- would seem unprofessional, and I would rather not use my personal account if I can avoid it while at a computer given by the company.

However dumb this may be, I haven't come up with a solution and I was thinking maybe someone else has though about this issue and can share some tips. (I know places that allow you to send files but they have a deadline on when to download them so I do not think that would solve the issue.)

Comment: Asking for tools or apps is off-optic here. I have removed that part from your question.

Comment: To be honest you should ask your company's IT or HR departments. You probably aren't the first person to have this concern at your company. I'm not comfortable giving you possible solutions that could be used to circumvent your company's IT polices.

Comment: That makes sense, and embarrisingly enough is probably the simplest approach and the one I wouldn't have thought about. On the other hand, just to clarify, I would not be circunventing anything, it is not forbidden nor restricted, I simply did not want to mix both accounts for personal reasons (probably even silly ones). Thanks for the answer though @Folk

Comment: @monkeyintern np, I didn't really think you wanted to circumvent anything, more that I didn't feel comfortable leaving ways that someone else could use considering how the question was worded. And I completely understand the personal / company separation. I bought a 2nd Android phone just for my work accounts. :) Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks for taking the time to explain, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just download the files and the emails and then move them to your personal machine using a USB or some other online file sharing tool, for example: WeShare?

Comment: Because I was worried it would get flagged as suspicious activity or get me under scrutiny, since we work with clients information. I want to do this for my own information, like payrolls and things like that.